# Iterating over boost graph vertexes based on maximal depth

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I would like to iterate over the vertexes of a graph based on the maximum depth of the vertex from any of the root vertexes.

Fore example the maximal depth of the vertex `I` is 3 (and is this annotated with this value in the graph below). Therefore any of the orderings would be acceptable: `{A , B , C , D} , {E , F , G} , {H}, {I}`, where any of the vertexes in curly braces `{}` can be ordered arbitrarily.

I have come across a somewhat [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199850/how-to-get-the-max-leveldepth-of-a-vertex-in-a-boost-graph) but it is geared towards getting the maximum depth of a single vertex and appears to assume a single root node.

[image]

I am quite new to boost graph but here is my feeble attempt at what a solution might resemble

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>

using namespace boost;

class depth_visitor : public default_dfs_visitor
{
public:
    template <typename Vertex , typename Graph >
    void discover_vertex(Vertex v , const Graph & g) const
    {
        // update 'depth' of vertex 
    }
};


int main()
{
  enum { A , B, C, D, E, F, G , H , I , COUNT };
  const char* name[] = { "A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" , "F" , "G" , "H" , "I" };

  typedef std::pair <int, int >Edge;
  Edge edge_array[] = { Edge(D, G), Edge(C, G), Edge(C, F), Edge(B, F), Edge(B, E), Edge(A, E),
                        Edge(G, H), Edge(F, I), Edge(E, H), Edge(H, I) };

    typedef adjacency_list < vecS, vecS, directedS > graph_t;
    graph_t g( edge_array , edge_array + sizeof(edge_array) / sizeof(E), COUNT );

    depth_visitor vis;
    depth_first_search( g , visitor( vis ) );
}
```

Comment: "maximum depth" in graph terms would probably be the length of the shortest path. In a tree this is easy, but boost graph is not constrained in this way. You'll need to enforce the graph is a tree. Anyway, you should be able to follow `boost::out_edges` until there are none in order to get your depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Andy said: you can traverse the out-edges manually.

Alternatively you can use [BFS](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/doc/breadth_first_search.html) with a custom visitor. You already had a similar idea.

Here's a realization of it:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
```

Now, let's define our types:

```
using Name   = char;
using Graph  = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Name>;
using Edge   = Graph::edge_descriptor;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
```

Let's create our own maximum distance recorder. This is roughly based on the [`distance_recorder<>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/doc/distance_recorder.html) class from Boost, which is an [EventVisitor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/doc/EventVisitor.html).

In our case, we'll have it filter for the `on_tree_edge` event only (because we don't care about non-tree graphs here).

```
using Depths = std::map<Vertex, size_t>;

struct Recorder : public boost::base_visitor<Recorder> {
    using event_filter = boost::on_tree_edge;

    Depths& _ref;
    Recorder(Depths& r):_ref(r){}

    void operator()(Edge e, const Graph& g) const {
        auto s = source(e, g), t = target(e, g);
        std::cout << "TREE EDGE " << g[s] << " -> " << g[t] << "\n";

        auto srcit = _ref.find(s);
        auto depth = srcit!=_ref.end()? srcit->second+1: 1;

        if (auto [it, isnew] = _ref.emplace(t, depth); !isnew) {
            it->second = std::max(it->second, depth);
        }
    }
};
```

You can see it basically just updates a `std::map` but with the following special treatments:

- when updating an existing value, it updates with the ***maximum** of the current distance and the previously recorded distance*.
- it does *not* insert depths for vertices not traveled to by a tree edge (basically, it doesn't use `operator[source_vertex]` which would insert entries with depth 0)

With that out of the way, all we need is to invoke the algorithm:

```
std::vector roots { A, B, C, D };

Depths depths;
Recorder r{depths};

for (auto root : roots)
    boost::breadth_first_search(
        g, root,
        queue, boost::make_bfs_visitor(r), color_map);

for (auto [v,d] : depths)
    std::cout << g[v] << " at " << d << "\n";
```

> Important Notes:
>
> - use `breadth_first_search` as opposed to `breadth_first_visit` because otherwise the `color_map` would not be re-initialized on each root node. This would make already-discovered nodes always be skipped, which means we would not *correctly get the **maximum** distance*
> - this is also the reason we couldn't use the *multi-source* overload like so:
>
>   ```
>   // WARNING BROKEN!
>   boost::breadth_first_search(
>           g, begin(roots), end(roots),
>           queue, boost::make_bfs_visitor(r), color_map);
>   ```
>
>   the effect would be the same because there's no re-initialization of the color-map for each root node.

### LIVE DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0268d2ec2d384934)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using Name   = char;
using Graph  = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Name>;
using Edge   = Graph::edge_descriptor;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

using Depths = std::map<Vertex, size_t>;

struct Recorder : public boost::base_visitor<Recorder> {
    using event_filter = boost::on_tree_edge;

    Depths& _ref;
    Recorder(Depths& r):_ref(r){}

    void operator()(Edge e, const Graph& g) const {
        auto s = source(e, g), t = target(e, g);
        std::cout << "TREE EDGE " << g[s] << " -> " << g[t] << "\n";

        auto srcit = _ref.find(s);
        auto depth = srcit!=_ref.end()? srcit->second+1: 1;

        if (auto [it, isnew] = _ref.emplace(t, depth); !isnew) {
            it->second = std::max(it->second, depth);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    enum : Vertex { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, COUNT };
    Graph g(COUNT);

    // give names
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        g[v] = 'A' + v;

    // add edges
    for (auto [s,t] : {
            std::pair(D,G), {D, G}, {C, G}, {C, F}, {B, F}, {B, E}, {A, E},
            {G, H}, {F, I}, {E, H},
            {H, I} })
    {
        add_edge(s, t, g);
    }

    std::vector roots { A, B, C, D };
    boost::queue<Vertex> queue;
    std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colors(num_vertices(g));
    auto color_map = boost::make_iterator_property_map(begin(colors), get(boost::vertex_index, g));

    Depths depths;
    Recorder r{depths};

    for (auto root : roots)
        boost::breadth_first_search(
            g, root,
            queue, boost::make_bfs_visitor(r), color_map);

    for (auto [v,d] : depths)
        std::cout << g[v] << " at " << d << "\n";
}
```

Which prints

```
TREE EDGE A -> E
TREE EDGE E -> H
TREE EDGE H -> I
TREE EDGE B -> F
TREE EDGE B -> E
TREE EDGE F -> I
TREE EDGE E -> H
TREE EDGE C -> G
TREE EDGE C -> F
TREE EDGE G -> H
TREE EDGE F -> I
TREE EDGE D -> G
TREE EDGE G -> H
TREE EDGE H -> I
E at 1
F at 1
G at 1
H at 2
I at 3
```

### UPDATE

Slightly altered to detect roots "by brute force":

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aa15cbe42af20c1)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using boost::make_iterator_range;
using Name   = char;
using Graph  = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Name>;
using Edge   = Graph::edge_descriptor;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

using Depths = std::map<Vertex, size_t>;

struct Recorder : public boost::base_visitor<Recorder> {
    using event_filter = boost::on_tree_edge;

    Depths& _ref;
    Recorder(Depths& r):_ref(r){}

    void operator()(Edge e, const Graph& g) const {
        auto depth = 1 + _ref[source(e, g)];

        if (auto [it, isnew] = _ref.emplace(target(e, g), depth); !isnew) {
            it->second = std::max(it->second, depth);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    enum : Vertex { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, COUNT };
    Graph g(COUNT);

    // give names
    for (auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        g[v] = 'A' + v;

    // add edges
    for (auto [s,t] : {
            std::pair(D,G), {D, G}, {C, G}, {C, F}, {B, F}, {B, E}, {A, E},
            {G, H}, {F, I}, {E, H},
            {H, I} })
    {
        add_edge(s, t, g);
    }

    boost::queue<Vertex> queue;
    std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colors(num_vertices(g));
    auto color_map = boost::make_iterator_property_map(begin(colors), get(boost::vertex_index, g));

    Depths depths;
    Recorder r{depths};

    for (auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        boost::breadth_first_search(g, v, queue, boost::make_bfs_visitor(r), color_map);
    }

    std::map<size_t, std::set<Vertex> > by_depth;
    for (auto [v,d] : depths)
        by_depth[d].insert(v);

    for (auto& [d,vs] : by_depth) {
        std::cout << "depth:" << d;
        for (auto v : vs) std::cout << " " << g[v];
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
depth:0 A B C D
depth:1 E F G
depth:2 H
depth:3 I
```

Comment: awesome! Thanks. Do you know if there is a function that can return the root vertexes or do I have to filter it out from `boost::vertices`?

Comment: You should be able to get a topological sort or use `in_degree` - you would have to change the graph model to support `in_degree` https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/doc/BidirectionalGraph.html.
But really, you could basically use all roots and see which would have 0 depth.

Comment: Here's that last idea implemented: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b36d8530a9fc100a (it's likely not the best you can do in terms of efficiency).

Comment: Maybe it's worth repeating for all nodes anyways and not bothering about locating roots - all nodes with depth 0 are implicitly roots: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aa15cbe42af20c1. **Updated answer**  I think I like it because it simplifies the Recorder as well. Added output by increasing depth, and with  ordered Vertices as well.

Comment: Rephrase: why is the `boost::breadth_first_search` outside the loop necessary?

Comment: @Olumide It isn't :embarrassed-smiley: I had removed it but apparently forgot to copy that to Coliru. Fixed: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cb069e253e8023e

Comment: Thanks! You probably need to modify the snippet in your post as well. (I am not worthy to edit your answers :humbly-bows-emoji:)

Comment: Oh you are :) Thanks for the hint